# Automatic Validation of Swagger API Request In Express?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

Excuse me if this question seems obvious, but I am new to Express, Node, and Swagger.

I have written a Swagger specification for an API.

Are there tools in which you can pass a request to a Swagger documented API along with the Swagger.json file to validate that the required parameters are there, that the enum values for those parameters are correct, etc.?

Something akin to:

```
validator.validate ("./swagger.json", req, function (req, res, err) {
     if (err) {
       res.status('400').send(err.message());
     }
     else {
       // Call my controller
       swaggerController(req, res);
     }
});
```

I believe there is, but it's difficult to find or I'm not looking for the correct thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. 
There is a generator project that does exactly this, express-no-stress. Get it [here](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress):

When using it, each API request will be validated against your Swagger API description, provided by you, in Api.yaml.

For example, to validate the `body` of a `POST` request to `/examples`, you can do the following:

Edit `Api.yaml`

```
...
definitions:
  # define the example body i.e. require the property name
  ExampleBody:
    type: object
    title: example
    required:
      - name
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: The example name
paths:
  # define your /examples POST endpoint
  # reference the ExamplesBody definition from above
  /examples:
    post:
      tags:
        - Examples
      description: Create a new example
      parameters:
        - name: example
          in: body
          description: number of items to skip
          required: true
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/ExampleBody"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Returns all examples
...
```

Next, in the Node.js code create a route handler for `POST`s to /examples

e.g.

`app.post('/examples', function (req, res) {
  /* your handler logic here */
  /* no need to validate the request payload. it will be done automatically */
});`

Note: include only your handler logic. Body validation will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of middleware for validating incoming responses against swagger json-schema.  Just a proof of concept but it may point you in the right direction:

[swagger-json-schema-middleware-example](https://gist.github.com/CacheControl/8f6e3db86c65674da6db2a19999993ea)